# How to avoid passing a leaf object through each class-node on the calling path using dependency injection, when only the leaf class needs that object?

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

I have a web application with a call chain that looks something like this:
[image]

In my Entity Repository I have a method that saves a "new record" in the entity table.  That method needs to also record *who* created the record.  In my case the user is identified by an `id`, which is an integer.

**This `id` itself is complicated.**

The `username` of the user is located in a `$_SESSION` variable.  I call a new `UserSession` object, which initializes itself with the `username`, and then makes a call to the database and loads the `User` object.  I can the use the object to get an `id` of the user.

**My Code is something like this:**

```
class EntityRepository
{
    function createNewRecord()
    {
        $userId = (new UserSession())->getUser()->getId();
        $this->createNewRecord("....$userId...");
    }
}
```

It is all great, but hey... `EntityRepository` depends on `UserSession`.  It therefore must be dependency injected.  So let's say we inject it.  But that creates a chain of dependencies, something like ..

```
$userSession = new UserSession();
$entityRepository =  new EntityRepository($userSession);
$mainRepository = new MainRepository($entityRepository);
$controller = new Controller($mainRepository);
```

I am dragging the `$userSession` object all through all the classes, including `MainRepository` and `Controller`, even though they themselves do not use `UserSession` and are just middle-men.

I am having an issue with passing the `UserSession` needlessly, when I use dependency injection techniques.

Is there a better way or am I doing it right?

Comment: You are missing a container, it can solve which object needs which other object and create them only when they are needed. Check [Php league's container](http://container.thephpleague.com/) for one.

Comment: thanks ... with a container I'm curious if by using it, if I will merely be hiding dependencies (aka have a similar fate to `Service Locator anti-pattern`).  Also I didn't yet understand how/where I will instantiate the actual container and whether the container itself will need to be passed to my leaf class via Dependency Injection, or if the container is global to the entire application...

Comment: If you pass the container itself then it would become a Service Locator pattern an it is [not recommended](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-11-container-meta.md#4-recommended-usage-container-psr-and-the-service-locator). The container would be global to the application, yes. You can see a usage example [here](http://container.thephpleague.com/3.x/basic-usage/).

Comment: @solarc is correct and you would only be service locating when passing around the injector to services. the point of DIC is to hierarchically instantiate all dependencies with added benefits of caching/sharing specific instances of classes you want to. rwlowrey/auryn is a good DIC

Comment: okay!  Reading about DIC I think I have a little bit more understanding, so let me ask -- when using a DIC (i.e. `auryn`), does that mean that I will need to **rewrite** the signature of my classes to accept the `userId` parameter? Because otherwise, I can instantiate the top-level class using DIC, but without having `userId` as a constructor-level parameter in all those classes on the chain to the leaf, how will I get `userId` to the leaf class?  Am I still missing something?

Comment: That is, to say, my understanding is that using a DIC won't *magically* put `userId` into my `EntityRepository` class, if the `EntityRepository` does not have a `__construct()` method that accepts `$userId` as a parameter.  As in I still need to put `$userId` as parameter into constructors of `EntityRepository` and `MainRepository`, and perhaps `Controller`, if I wish to have access to `$userId` inside the `EntityRepository`.  Is that correct?